# How to get sound working in chroot(Linux on Android)

Tags: fedora, audio, kde, android

I have Fedora 21 KDE running on Sony Xperia Tablet Z and it seems my device sound card and M-Audio(M-Track) USB sound card is detected.

[image: Screenshot]
But yet no audio output. What is best way to solve this issue?